# What is the best Implementation for a Multigraph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, implementation, edges

In both space and operation cost which is the best way to implement a multigraph that has more edges than vertices?

In the worst case it would have 5000 edges and 1000 vertices.  I was thinking of an adjacency list because it has a great time for most of the operations like `add edges`, `check adjacency between edges`, `add vertices` (almost all the time), etc.... but it still consumes a space of   `|v^2|`.

Am I on the right track?  Is there a better implementation?  Any tips on the best way to implement the the adjacency list?

Comment: The adacency list is O(V+E), not O(V^2). Where did You get O(V^2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ratio `E/V = 5` means really really sparse graphs, which is a plus for lists. In general adjacency lists are overall better than adjacency matrices.

Now the cost of insertion is `O(degree(vertex))` but with so few edges it will be negligible. 
Don't look further, use adjacency lists.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will keep going with the list then. :)